# Determine the missing entries of a matrix given the characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra

> The characteristic polynomial of the matrix below is $t^3-4t-1$. Determine the missing entries. $$M= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & \ast & \ast \end{pmatrix} $$

I tried calculating $\det(M-tI)$ and then setting that equal to $t^3-4t-1$, but I end up with an ugly expression $-t(1-t)(\ast-t)-(\ast-t)+2 \ast - (1-t)$, for which I am having trouble finding the $\ast$ that will make it equal to $t^3-4t-1$. How do I continue from here? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Are both $*$ supposed to be the same - the question reads as if they can be different. If you know something about the trace of a matrix, that could help.

Comment: @MarkBennet Not sure, but I suspect that they might be different. I will box all the information given in the textbook (Michael Artin's Algebra)

Comment: Note: The trace of a matrix (sum of the diagonal entries) is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues which is equal to the sum of the roots of the equation which is ... Also: using $*$ in your workings where the two entries represented by $*$ and different is bound to cause you confusion - you need to call them different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$M= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & a & b \end{pmatrix} \\
\implies -\det(M-tI_3)=t(t-1)(t-b)+(b-t)+2(1-a-t)\\
\implies -(b+1)=0,\quad b+2(1-a)=-1\\
\implies a=-b=1$$